MariaDB repair failed
I was making a page with WordPress and when I started MariaDB I got the following red banner and it wouldn't let me start it:
    15:34:02  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
    15:34:02  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
    15:34:02  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
    15:34:02  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
    15:34:02  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
    15:34:02  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
    15:34:02  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums

Then I went into the errors and I got an error in a table, but I have no idea what to do to fix it. This is the second time this has happened to me, the first time I lost my project (I'm very new to this).
    2024-04-08 15:33:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
    2024-04-08 15:33:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
    2024-04-08 15:33:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.32 started; log sequence number 101970487; transaction id 44548
    2024-04-08 15:33:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from     C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
    2024-04-08 15:33:55 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
    2024-04-08 15:33:55 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
    2024-04-08 15:33:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 240408 15:33:55
    2024-04-08 15:33:55 0 [ERROR] **mysqld.exe: Table '.\mysql\db' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed**
    2024-04-08 15:33:55 0 [ERROR]** Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table '.\mysql\db' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed**
    2024-04-08 15:33:55 0 [ERROR] Aborting

I hope you can help me, thank you very much!

Does this answer your question? Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.host' doesn't exist
